# Effects of modiflying Progress database field validation

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm working on a Progress Version 9 OpenEdge system and would like to change the database field validation.

Can you tell me if this will have any knock on effects? I've been warned not to modify the database tables as this will result in the field/table checksum to be modified which then leads to problems. Will modifying the validation on a field had adverse effects like that?

Thanks in advance, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're concerned about breaking existing r-code?

Changing validation does not impact existing r-code.

However... validation is a very poor way to do much of anything.  It's one of those features that "makes a nice demo" but, in practice, it has serious downsides.  In particular you are binding your UI layer and your data access layer very tightly together by using validation.